# How to combine multiple CSS declarations to shorthand

Tags: c#, css, .net, anglesharp

I'm using [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) to parse some CSS files, compare their structure and build an output file out of them. The tool makes all declarations explicit, i.e. if the source rule is:

```
.recent-work-wrap .overlay {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

I get following output from AngleSharp:

```
.recent-work-wrap .overlay {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

That is good for comparing rules and detect changes, but the question is, how can this rule be combined to a shorthand like above?

So for another example, how to get from this:

```
    .sample-rule {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

to this

```
    .sample-rule {
        margin: 30px auto;
    }
```

The situation gets worse with CSS3 declarations, because they can really have a lot of parameters... I checked some CSS minifier/uglifier tools, but they mostly use RegEx to remove whitespace and smaller optimizations.
Is there a known way/tool/library to write optimal shorthands out of multiple declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get this output? Have you tried looking at the shorthand declarations (e.g., `Margin`) of the `Style` property?

Internally, AngleSharp only uses longhand declarations, thus the output is as verbose as it could be. However, AngleSharp knows most shorthands and should be able to recombine these longhands into their shorthand form.

I don't know if that helps you already. If not then please post some code (a MWE) and I'll try refine this answer.

Comment: I'll try to build a minimum example. But basically, I'm iterating over the rules in an ICssStyleSheet and storing/producing output for each rule. So what you are saying is, I could build the rules programmatically (not parsing a CSS string) in AngleScript and get shorthanded code by calling `ToCss()`?

Comment: Somewhat, yes. Usually, `ToCss()` should already try to get shorthand notations (if possible), however, you can force that representation by calling the shorthand declarations directly (see above example with `Margin`, which is the shorthand for `MarginTop`, `MarginBottom`, etc. reflecting the respective CSS declaration `margin-top`, ...).

Comment: That works beautifully, AngleSharp is just AWESOME! :) I'm not sure if those "initial" values are correct though.

Comment: Could be - if you feel anything is wrong or fishy, just create an issue on the AngleSharp repo at GitHub. I'll look at it there! (Don't worry if it turns out to be correct behavior, though - better be safe than sorry ;D)